# Regex C++: extract substring from a string then count each word

Tags: c++, regex, substring, extract

I have strings of text in the format below.

```
*tag0 hi how are you tag1 where are you from tag3 i would like to eat some food*
```

The text is in a vector and I assigned it to a variable string *line2*. I want to extract the words from each of the tag and count it as token. Below is my code.

```
smatch t_headermatch;
regex re("tag[0-9]+");

for (int i = 0; i < (int)boxraw.size(); ++i) {          
    line2 = boxraw.at(i); 

while (regex_search(line2, t_headermatch, re)){
        for (auto x : t_headermatch)cout << x << " ";

//If find tag header, print the words after the header and count it as token.

//repeat the process until found a new tag header.exit if no tag found


        cout <<endl;
        line2 = t_headermatch.suffix().str();
    }
```

My expected ouput would be something like below:

```
Found 3 tag

tag0
hi token 1
how token 2
are token 3
you token 4
tag1
where 1 
are  2 
you 3
tag3 
i 1
would 2
like 3
to 4
eat 5
some 6
food 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex

```
"tag\\d+((?:\\s+(?!tag)\\w+)+)"
```

Each `regex_search` will return `match_result` object

```
t_headermatch[0] : the whole match, i.e. "tag0 hi how are you"
t_headermatch[1] : the substring with tokens "hi how are you"
```

Also you need to split tokens and etc.